# Laravel 10.x -> 11.x upgrade composer error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

My app was running Laravel 10.x and PHP 8.2. I upgraded the app to run on 8.3 and everything went fine. THen, i tried upgrading to Laravel 11.x using the Laravel Shift service.

I got an error on my composer running on the PR Laravel Shift created. I checked out the Shift branch and manually ran `composer update` and I am getting the following error.

I have the hardest time with composer errors, they seem not very descriptive of what the actual issue is or I am just not reading them correctly.

Any ideas on what the problem is?

```
Problem 1
    - symfony/http-foundation[v4.3.0-BETA1, ..., v4.4.8] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.3.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/routing[v5.6.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.3.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http[v7.0.0, ..., v7.28.4] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.3.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/routing[v7.0.0, ..., v7.28.4] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.3.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http[v7.29.0, ..., 7.x-dev] require symfony/mime ^5.0 -> found symfony/mime[v5.0.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0).
    - illuminate/routing[v6.0.0, ..., v6.19.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.3.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/routing[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.3.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.3.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/http-foundation[v4.4.9, ..., 4.4.x-dev] require symfony/mime ^4.3|^5.0 -> found symfony/mime[v4.3.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev, v5.0.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0).
    - illuminate/http[v8.12.0, ..., v8.18.0] require symfony/mime ^5.1 -> found symfony/mime[v5.1.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0).
    - illuminate/http[v8.18.1, ..., v8.73.2] require symfony/mime ^5.1.4 -> found symfony/mime[v5.1.4, ..., 5.4.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0).
    - illuminate/http[v8.74.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require symfony/mime ^5.4 -> found symfony/mime[v5.4.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0).
    - illuminate/http[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev] require symfony/mime ^6.0 -> found symfony/mime[v6.0.0-BETA1, ..., 6.4.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0).
    - illuminate/http[v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev] require symfony/mime ^6.2 -> found symfony/mime[v6.2.0-BETA1, ..., 6.4.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0).
    - balping/laravel-hashslug 2.2.4 requires illuminate/routing 5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0|^9.0|^10.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/routing[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev, v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev].
    - balping/laravel-hashslug 2.2.3 requires illuminate/routing 5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0|^9.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/routing[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev].
    - balping/laravel-hashslug 2.2.2 requires illuminate/routing 5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/routing[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
    - balping/laravel-hashslug[2.2.0, ..., 2.2.1] require illuminate/routing 5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/routing[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev].
    - illuminate/routing[v5.5.0, ..., 5.5.x-dev] require symfony/http-foundation ~3.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v3.3.0-BETA1, ..., 3.4.x-dev].
    - symfony/http-client[v7.0.0-BETA1, ..., 7.1.x-dev] conflict with symfony/http-foundation v3.4.47.
    - symfony/http-client[v7.0.0-BETA1, ..., 7.1.x-dev] conflict with symfony/http-foundation v3.3.18.
    - symfony/http-client[v7.0.0-BETA1, ..., 7.1.x-dev] conflict with symfony/http-foundation v3.3.6.
    - illuminate/routing[v7.29.0, ..., 7.x-dev] require illuminate/http ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev].
    - illuminate/routing[v6.20.0, ..., 6.x-dev] require symfony/http-foundation ^4.3.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.3.4, ..., 4.4.x-dev].
    - illuminate/routing[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require illuminate/http ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
    - illuminate/routing[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev] require illuminate/http ^9.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev].
    - illuminate/routing[v10.34.0, ..., 10.x-dev] require illuminate/http ^10.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev].
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/http-client ^7.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-client[v7.0.0-BETA1, ..., 7.1.x-dev].
    - Root composer.json requires balping/laravel-hashslug ^2.2 -> satisfiable by balping/laravel-hashslug[2.2.0, ..., 2.2.4].
```

Here's my composer file as well:

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "require": {
    "php": "^8.3",
    "algolia/scout-extended": "^3.1",
    "balping/laravel-hashslug": "^2.2",
    "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "^2.27",
    "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^11.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^3.5",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "intervention/image": "^2.7",
    "itsgoingd/clockwork": "^5.2",
    "jorenvanhocht/laravel-share": "^4.2",
    "josiasmontag/laravel-recaptchav3": "^1.0",
    "laravel/cashier": "^15.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^11.1",
    "laravel/jetstream": "^5.0",
    "laravel/pulse": "dev-validation-errors",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^4.0",
    "laravel/slack-notification-channel": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.9",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.0",
    "livewire/livewire": "^3.3",
    "pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg": "^8.5",
    "php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth": "^2.2",
    "ramsey/uuid": "^4.2",
    "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^4.2",
    "spatie/calendar-links": "^1.8",
    "spatie/laravel-schedule-monitor": "^3.7",
    "symfony/http-client": "^7.0",
    "symfony/mailgun-mailer": "^7.0",
    "symfony/mime": "^7.0",
    "understand/understand-laravel": "^2.7"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "brianium/paratest": "^7.3",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.26",
    "laravel/telescope": "^5.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.6",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^8.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.5",
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.4",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
      "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
      "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "dont-discover": [
        "laravel/telescope"
      ]
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
      "php-http/discovery": true
    }
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I can't upload the whole file since it's too big, but here are some places `symfony/http-foundation`  is used in my `composer.lock` file:

```
"symfony/http-foundation": "^4.4|^5.4|^6|^7"

{
    "name": "symfony/http-foundation",
    "version": "v6.4.0",
    "source": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation.git",
        "reference": "44a6d39a9cc11e154547d882d5aac1e014440771"
    },
    "dist": {
        "type": "zip",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/http-foundation/zipball/44a6d39a9cc11e154547d882d5aac1e014440771",
        "reference": "44a6d39a9cc11e154547d882d5aac1e014440771",
        "shasum": ""
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "symfony/deprecation-contracts": "^2.5|^3",
        "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "~1.1",
        "symfony/polyfill-php83": "^1.27"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/cache": "<6.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.13.1|^3|^4",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1|^2.0",
        "symfony/cache": "^6.3|^7.0",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^5.4|^6.0|^7.0",
        "symfony/expression-language": "^5.4|^6.0|^7.0",
        "symfony/http-kernel": "^5.4.12|^6.0.12|^6.1.4|^7.0",
        "symfony/mime": "^5.4|^6.0|^7.0",
        "symfony/rate-limiter": "^5.4|^6.0|^7.0"
    },
    "type": "library",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\": ""
        },
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "/Tests/"
        ]
    },
    "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
    "license": [
        "MIT"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Fabien Potencier",
            "email": "fabien@symfony.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Symfony Community",
            "homepage": "https://symfony.com/contributors"
        }
    ],
    "description": "Defines an object-oriented layer for the HTTP specification",
    "homepage": "https://symfony.com",
    "support": {
        "source": "https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/tree/v6.4.0"
    },
    "funding": [
        {
            "url": "https://symfony.com/sponsor",
            "type": "custom"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://github.com/fabpot",
            "type": "github"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://tidelift.com/funding/github/packagist/symfony/symfony",
            "type": "tidelift"
        }
    ],
    "time": "2023-11-20T16:41:16+00:00"
},

"symfony/http-foundation": "^6.4|^7.0",

"symfony/http-foundation": "<6.2"

"symfony/http-foundation": "^5.4|^6.0|^7.0",

"symfony/http-foundation": "^5.2|^6.0|^7.0",
```

Comment: `symfony/http-foundation[v4.3.0-BETA1, ..., v4.4.8] require php ^7.1.3` https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range- `^7.1.3` means "greater than 7.1.3, but less than 8". You are using PHP version 8.x.

Comment: I guess i'm just confused why things were working fine with Laravel 10.x and PHP 8.2 which is what my previous setup was. How can i find out where `symfony/http-foundation` is coming from?

Comment: You can look in the `composer.lock` to figure out what package has `symfony/http-foundation` as a dependency.

Comment: @bassxzero i added the instances where `symfony/http-foundation ` is referenced from my `composer.lock` file.